# Solving following quartic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Solve in $\mathbb{R}$ :

$$(x^2+2)^2+8x^2=6x (x^2+2) $$

My try: I tried to make the graph by calculating values for  $x=1, 2, 3, 4$ and I found that the function is positive at $x=0$ but negative at $x=1$, so the graph must have crossed the $x$ axis, thus there will be a root between $0$ and $1$ and similarly this was the case between $3$ and $4$, but I was unable to solve it precisely. I was also unable to find about the other two roots.

What is the way to solve it just by algebra or rough plotting with the help of pen and paper and not using any computational tools?

Answer (score 15):

**Let,** $$y=x^2+2$$

**Now,**

$y^2-6xy+8x^2=0$

$\implies \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 -6\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)+8=0$

$\implies y = 4x$

or

$y=2x$

$\implies x^2-4x+2=0$

or

$x^2-2x+2=0$

$\implies x = 2 \pm \sqrt{2}, 1 \pm i$

Comment: You should solve in $\mathbb{R}$, so $1\pm i$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$(x^2+2)^2+8x^2=6x(x^2+2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^4+4x^2+4+8x^2=6x(x^2+2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^4+12x^2+4=6x(x^2+2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^4+12x^2+4=6x^3+12x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^4+12x^2-6x^3-12x+4=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x^2-4x+2)(x^2-2x+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x^2-4x+2)=0\vee (x^2-2x+2)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2-4x=-2\vee x^2-2x=-2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2-4x+4=-2+4\vee x^2-2x+1=-2+1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(x-2)^2=2\vee (x-1)^2=-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x-2=\sqrt{2}\vee x-2=-\sqrt{2}\vee -\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=2+\sqrt{2}\vee x=2-\sqrt{2}\vee -\Longleftrightarrow$$

"$-$" $\rightarrow$ $(x-1)^2=-1$ has no real solutions

So:

$$(x^2+2)^2+8x^2=6x(x^2+2)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=2+\sqrt{2} \vee x=2-\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: I'm not sure I could have seen that $(x^2-4x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$ is a factorization of $x^4+12x^2-6x^3-12x+4$ just be examining the latter equation. How did you do it?

Comment: First you've write out your equation and subtract everything, then you get something that ends with $=0$ than you look for the way to write it $()()=0$

Comment: Yes, we got the "something that ends with $=0$" part; that was easy. It's the "look for the way to write it $()()=0$" that is a mystery.

Comment: @DavidK  Posit a solution $$x^4 - 6x^3 + 12x^2 - 12x + 4 = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$$  Matching coefficients yields \begin{align*} a + c & = -6\\ ac + b + d & = 12\\ ad + bc & = -12\\ bd & = 4\end{align*}  The choice $b = 1, d = 4$ leads to the contradiction $a + c = -6$, $ac = 7$.  The choice $b = 2, d = 2$ yields $a + c = -6$ and $ac = 8$, from which you can determine that $a = -4$ and $c = -2$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding the equation:

$$ x^4 + 4x^2 + 4+ 8x^2 = 6x^3 + 12x$$

$$x^4 -6x^3 +12x^2-12x+4=0$$

You can then factorise the above expression

Alternatively, you can replace $x^2 + 2$ with $y$ which gives you:

$$ y^2 + 8x^2 = 6xy$$

$$ (y-4x)(y-2x) = 0$$

$$ y = 4x$$ or $$ y = 2x$$
Now replace $y$ with $x^2 + 2$

$x^2 + 2 = 4x  $  or $x^2 + 2 = 2x$

$$(x^2 -4x +2)(x^2-2x+2) = 0 $$

Comment: I tried to expand but was unable to factorise it.

Comment: @John the solutions are ugly radicals. Of course, one could factorise any polynomial, but it doesn't work this case.

Comment: @wythagoras, you're right, it doesnt factorise nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Given that
$$(x^2+2)^2+8x^2=6x(x^2+2)$$
Put $x^2+2=y$. Then
$$y^2+8x^2=6xy$$
$$8x^2-6xy+y^2=0$$
$$8x^2-4xy-2xy+y^2=0$$
$$4x(2x-y)-y(2x-y)=0$$
$$(4x-y)(2x-y)=0$$
$$(4x-x^2-2)(2x-x^2-2)=0$$
$$(x^2-4x+2)(x^2-2x+2)=0$$
Now we have
$$x^2-4x+2=0$$
This is quadratic eq
$$x=\frac{-(-4) \pm \sqrt{(-4)^2-4(1)(2)}}{2(1)}$$
$$x=\frac{4 \pm 2\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
$$ x=2 \pm \sqrt{2}$$
Similarly we have second eq
$$x^2-2x+2=0$$
Bu quadratic formula
$$x=\frac{-(-2) \pm \sqrt{(-2)^2-4(1)(2)}}{2(1)}$$
$$x=\frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4(-1)}}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{2 \pm 2\sqrt{-1}}{2}$$
$$x=1 \pm i$$
As $\sqrt{-1}=i$.

So all roots of "$x$" we have
$$x=2 \pm \sqrt{2} , 1 \pm i $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Rewrite it as:

$$(x^2+2)^2-6x(x^2+2)+8x^2=0$$

Now use the substitution $$y=\frac{x^2+2}{x}$$

This gives

$$x^2y^2-6x^2y+8x^2=0$$

Therefore $$x^2=0 \vee y^2-6y+8=0$$

Comment: How did you thought about it?I tried to put $y=x^2+2 $

Comment: @KartikWatwani because the term with $(x^2+2)^2$ has no $x$, the term with $(x^2+2)$ has one $x$, the term without it has $x^2$. This is asymmetric, thus this technique can be used.

Comment: What do you mean when you say asymmetric? @wythagoras

Comment: @KartikWatwani The polynomial in $y=x^2+2$ and $x$ has an equal number of factors ($x,y$) in each term. Then it can be used.

Comment: I didnt got you.

Comment: $x=0$ does not satisfy the given equation – LHS is 4 while RHS is 0.

Comment: @CiaPan ya I know that.

Comment: @CiaPan Indeed, which is why you always need to check all your solutions at the end. It is a false solution because you divide by 0 in $y$.

Comment: @Kartik Watwani: in the equation, set $y=x^2+2$. The equation rewrites as: $\;y^2+8x^2=6xy$, which is a homogeneous function of $x$ and $y$. The standard method to solve it is to set $t=y/x$ (or $x/y$), whichbrings us back to an  equation in 1 variable.

Comment: @wythagoras And due to such 'false results' one should check *before* the division if the zero is a solution (so it appears soon, if valid), then explicitly exclude it from further calculations (so it won't appear late as a false solution). It's much better (and sometimes easier) to not introduce false results, than eliminate them by additional checking at the end.